# Хваленного берегись пуще хаянного.

Tags: грамматика, орфоэпия

В словаре Даля натолкнулся на пословицу:

> > Хвалёного берегись пуще хаяного.

Мне кажется, что корректнее было бы такое написание:

> > Хвале**нн**ого берегись пуще хая**нн**ого.

Мои рассуждения:

1. Слова "хаяный" в словарях нет, только "хаяННый".
2. Логично предположить, что слова "хаянный" и "хваленный" должны писаться однообразно: если "хаянный", даже будучи в данном случае отглагольным прилагательным, пишется как причастие (с двумя "н"), и то "хваленный" должно писаться как причастие, а не как прилагательное (то есть не "хвалёный"). Для симметрии, так сказать.
3. Уверен, что порядок слов неслучаен, прослеживается рифма: "Хв**а**ленного берегись пуще х**а**янного". С прилагательным "хвал**ё**ный" такое невозможно.

Прав ли я? Почему есть прилагательное "хвалёный", но нет "хаяный"? Почему в словаре Даля есть пословица со словом "хая**н**ый"? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ХВАЛЁНЫЙ - прилагательное (ирон.)Расхваленный, высоко оцененный (обычно о ком-, чём-л., не оправдавшем похвалы, вызвавшем разочарование). Х-ые достижения, достоинства, рекорды. Вот они, ваши х-ые работнички!

Здесь, скорее, причастие ХВАЛЕННЫЙ - тот, которого много хвалили (иронии и разочарования нет). Соответственно, ХАЯННЫЙ - тот, которого много ругали.

Получается: хвАленного берегись пуще хАянного. Такой вариант в текстах встречается, и мне он кажется наиболее правильным. Но другие сочетания также бывают.